# What am I missing from this script to scrape a row of a table from a webpage?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As you can see, I've made my very first novice attempt to scrape [this webpage](http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100?list=2). This is [how I found the code](https://imgur.com/a/qIM4e). So as you can see, I inspected, found td, and what I want is in td a href.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

# URL for the table
url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100?list=2'
#grab the page
html = requests.get(url).text
#import into BS
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup)

#find data we want, starting with first row
for item_name in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "table-item-link"}):
    print(table-item-link.text)
```

**My objective:** Scrape the page, grabbing the name of the item, and then placing the name of that item into a table, possibly. I'm not writing to CSV yet, as I'm way too novice for that. Just taking it one step at a time. For this step, I'm just trying to figure out how to grab the item name, and store it into a table. Next, I will learn how to move to the next object in the table I want to grab, the total rise, and then finally the percent change.

**end goal:** to be able to scrape a table like this, grab everything I need from each row, and store it into my own table, then export to CSV. But I'm not there yet, so one step at a time!

Comment: Can you add the html from the page? A few rows of the table with representative data in them would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you need. Creating a CSV file using Python's library is quite straight forward. It simply takes a list of items and writes them correctly as comma separated entries for you into the file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

header = ['Item', 'Start price', 'End price', 'Total Rise', 'Change']
url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100?list=2'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find("a", {"class": "table-item-link"}).parent.parent.parent

with open('prices.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        row = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
        del row[1]
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you an output `prices.csv` starting as:

```
Item,Start price,End price,Total Rise,Change
Opal bolt tips,2,3,1,+50%
Half plain pizza,541,727,186,+34%
Poorly-cooked bird mea...,79,101,22,+27%
```

I use `.parent.parent.parent` simply to work backwards to find the start of the containing table for the entry that you were looking for.

The HTML table is composed of a load of `<tr>` elements, and within each are a load of `<td>` elements. So the trick is to first find the table, then using this, use `find_all()` to iterate through all of the `<tr>` elements inside it. Then with each of these `<td>` elements, use the `get_text(strip=True)` to extract the text inside each element. `strip=True` removes any extra newlines or spaces to ensure you just get the text you need.

I used a Python list comprehension to create the list of values in each row. A separate for loop could also be used, and might be easier to understand initially, e.g.

```
row = []

for td in tr.find_all('td'):
    row.append(td.get_text(strip=True))
```

Note, the advantage of using Python's CSV library rather than simply writing the information yourself to the file is that if any of the values were to contain a comma in them, it would automatically correctly enclose the entry in quotes for you.

Comment: Is there anyway to skip over or get rid of the first column? It keeps creating empty comma separated data as you can see by the double comma. Hmmm

Comment: Simply use `csv_output.writerow(row[1:])`  (and remember to adjust the header accordingly), or do you mean the second column i.e. between `item` and `start price`?  If so, use `del row[1]` instead before the write row.

Comment: Why do some scripts use "html.parser", and others use "lxml"? What is the difference? 
Sorry, I know I have a million questions xD

Comment: The later is a bit more powerful and faster but usually needs installing separately. The first is usually sufficient for most needs.

Answer (score 2):

I edited your code to get the item :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

# URL for the table
url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100?list=2'
#grab the page
html = requests.get(url).text
#import into BS
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
#find data we want, starting with first row
# Tag is <a> not <td> as <td> is just holding the <a> tags
# You were also not using the right var name in your for loop
for item_name in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "table-item-link"}):
    print(item_name.text)
```

To store your data easily in any format, I suggest [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/) which is well documented and can handle many formats.